# You must pass in a non null View

Tags: android, view, navigation, android-appcompat, drawer

I recently updated my project to the Android Support Library 23.1 and this part of my code now gives an error.

It was working before the update and commenting just this part out allows me to run the app fine.What exactly is wrong or has change?

```
Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(R.drawable.banner)
            .fitCenter()
            .override(width, height / 2)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
            .into(back);

    if (picture != null) {
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(picture)
                .fitCenter()
                .override(width / 2, height / 2)
                .into(profile);
    } else {
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(R.drawable.profile_p)
                .fitCenter()
                .override(width / 2, height / 2)
                .into(profile);
    }
```

This is the error log.

```
    10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime: Process: atsystems.cal, PID: 16313
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{atsystems.cal/atsystems.cal.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:678)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.bumptech.glide.DrawableRequestBuilder.into(DrawableRequestBuilder.java:448)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at atsystems.cal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:74)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
10-16 22:41:27.238 16313-16313/atsystems.cal E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I am using a navigation drawer layout which contains a navigation view.This navigation view contains the header layout which i display and as it turns out the code which i commented out is used to display pictures for the header layout.So has anything changed in the new library update?

Comment: Check and make sure that 'back' and 'profile' are non-null.

Comment: please check line 74 of your mainActivity as that is where your error lays.

Comment: The exact same code works before the 23.1.0 update,i reverted and checked too.It would seem that there is a problem with the app:headerLayout feature of the navigation view not finding the header layout anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would seem that there is an issue regarding the navigation view.
[NavigationView findViewById can't find header view](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190226)

The current fix/workaround is to find the header layout using.

```
final NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    final View headerLayout = mNavigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.header);
```

Once that is done you can refer to each element in the header layout like so.

```
final ImageView profile = (ImageView) headerLayout.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

Answer (score 1):

Jude answer is correct; but if you do not want to inflate the header view again, try this version:

```
final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
final View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.